# O bug com o garbage collection (coletor de lixo) foi corrigido em qual versão do PHP?

Tags: php, garbage-collector

> Error: PHP Notice: session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir:
>   opendir(/var/lib/php/session) failed: Permission denied (13)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904862/issues-with-php-5-3-and-sessions-folder

Atualizar o PHP resolveria o meu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, se você atualizar para o PHP 5.3 resolverá seu problema do garbage collector, uma vez que ele existe nesta versão do PHP.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.gc.php

De toda forma, sempre recomendo a atualizar para a última versão da série que você está utilizando, no seu caso para o PHP `5.6.27`.

Comment: Boa noite. Eu estou utilizando atualmente a versão 5.3. Eu gostaria de saber se o erro deixaria de acontecer em outras versões do PHP 5. Meu servidor fica indisponível e o problema parece ocorrer por culpa do garbage collector.

Comment: Então o seu problema não é de versão do PHP, e sim de permissão nesta pasta de sessão. Tente dar permissão para ela com esse comando:

Comment: `sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/session`